# AR Core Persistent Cloud Anchors TTL

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm making something like this:
[image]

I want to keep the anchor indefinitely. To do so, TTL must last more than 365 days.

solutions:

1. Extend 365 days again when it expires.
2. Replicate existing anchors and keep them indefinitely.

Possible implementation of these?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the anchors from ARCore Cloud Anchor Management API and extend the TTL periodically. The process & example API requests are described here:
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/cloud-anchors/management-api